# Windows: obtain LDAP Organizational Unit

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, ldap

I have a User GUID. How could I get the Organizational Unit (OU) of this user?

Answer (score -1):

This [forum response](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/netfxbcl/thread/bc704849-c11c-426b-9af6-5277a4091ac1) shows how to generate the proper LDAP query, after that you just need to fetch the OU attribute from the returned object.

Comment: its done by 1- connect to user  2 - get user parent 3- get OU

Comment: border line link only